# Translate 2D SDF functions to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, shader, translate

I would like to translate some of the 2D SDF functions from this very nice page here into JavaScript:
https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm

I could already translate the functions sdCircle and sdBox. I would like to translate all functions and use them directly in JavaScript. Currently I'm working on the sdTriangle function. I can't get any further here. sdTriangle returns always NaN. I guess the problem occurs on the way to calculate dX and dY. But I'm absolutely not sure where the error could be.

I have already successfully translated sdCircle and sdBox to JavaScript.

```
float sdCircle( vec2 p, float r )
{
  return length(p) - r;
}
```

becomes:

```
function signedDistanceToCircle( p, center, radius ) {

  const dx = p.x - center.x;
  const dy = p.y - center.y;

  return Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy ) - radius;

}
```

And

```
float sdBox( in vec2 p, in vec2 b )
{
    vec2 d = abs(p)-b;
    return length(max(d,vec2(0))) + min(max(d.x,d.y),0.0);
}
```

becomes:

```
function signedDistanceToBox( p, center, size ) {

  const offsetX = Math.abs( p.x - center.x ) - size / 2;
  const offsetY = Math.abs( p.y - center.y ) - size / 2;

  const offsetMaxX = Math.max( offsetX, 0 );
  const offsetMaxY = Math.max( offsetY, 0 );
  const offsetMinX = Math.min( offsetX, 0 );
  const offsetMinY = Math.min( offsetY, 0 );

  const unsignedDst = Math.sqrt( offsetMaxX * offsetMaxX + offsetMaxY * offsetMaxY );
  const dstInsideBox = Math.max( offsetMinX, offsetMinY );

  return unsignedDst + dstInsideBox;

}
```

You can see the whole thing in action here:
https://cutt.ly/owFbqxw

Now it's about the sdTriangle function:

```
float sdTriangle( in vec2 p, in vec2 p0, in vec2 p1, in vec2 p2 )
{
    vec2 e0 = p1-p0, e1 = p2-p1, e2 = p0-p2;
    vec2 v0 = p -p0, v1 = p -p1, v2 = p -p2;
    vec2 pq0 = v0 - e0*clamp( dot(v0,e0)/dot(e0,e0), 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec2 pq1 = v1 - e1*clamp( dot(v1,e1)/dot(e1,e1), 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec2 pq2 = v2 - e2*clamp( dot(v2,e2)/dot(e2,e2), 0.0, 1.0 );
    float s = sign( e0.x*e2.y - e0.y*e2.x );
    vec2 d = min(min(vec2(dot(pq0,pq0), s*(v0.x*e0.y-v0.y*e0.x)),
                     vec2(dot(pq1,pq1), s*(v1.x*e1.y-v1.y*e1.x))),
                     vec2(dot(pq2,pq2), s*(v2.x*e2.y-v2.y*e2.x)));
    return -sqrt(d.x)*sign(d.y);
}
```

And here's my try:

```
function signedDistanceToTriangle( p, p0, p1, p2 ) {

  const edge0X = p1.x - p0.x;
  const edge0Y = p1.y - p0.y;
  const edge1X = p2.x - p1.x;
  const edge1Y = p2.y - p1.y;
  const edge2X = p0.x - p2.x;
  const edge2Y = p0.y - p2.y;

  const v0X = p.x - p0.x;
  const v0Y = p.y - p0.y;
  const v1X = p.x - p1.x;
  const v1Y = p.y - p1.y;
  const v2X = p.x - p2.x;
  const v2Y = p.y - p2.y;

  const pq0X = v0X - edge0X * clamp( dot( v0X, edge0X ) / dot( edge0X, edge0X ), 0, 1 );
  const pq0Y = v0Y - edge0Y * clamp( dot( v0Y, edge0Y ) / dot( edge0Y, edge0Y ), 0, 1 );
  const pq1X = v1X - edge1X * clamp( dot( v1X, edge1X ) / dot( edge1X, edge1X ), 0, 1 );
  const pq1Y = v1Y - edge1Y * clamp( dot( v1Y, edge1Y ) / dot( edge1Y, edge1Y ), 0, 1 );
  const pq2X = v2X - edge2X * clamp( dot( v2X, edge2X ) / dot( edge2X, edge2X ), 0, 1 );
  const pq2Y = v2Y - edge2Y * clamp( dot( v2Y, edge2Y ) / dot( edge2Y, edge2Y ), 0, 1 );

  const s = Math.sign( edge0X * edge2Y - edge0Y * edge2X );

  const dotPQ0X = dot( pq0X, pq0X );
  const dotPQ0Y = dot( pq0Y, pq0Y );
  const dotPQ1X = dot( pq1X, pq1X );
  const dotPQ1Y = dot( pq1Y, pq1Y );
  const dotPQ2X = dot( pq2X, pq2X );
  const dotPQ2Y = dot( pq2Y, pq2Y );

  const s0 = s * ( v0X * edge0Y - v0Y * edge0X );
  const s1 = s * ( v1X * edge1Y - v1Y * edge1X );
  const s2 = s * ( v2X * edge2Y - v2Y * edge2X );

  const dX = Math.min( Math.min( dotPQ0X, s0, dotPQ1X, s1 ), dotPQ2X, s2 );
  const dY = Math.min( Math.min( dotPQ0Y, s0, dotPQ1Y, s1 ), dotPQ2Y, s2 );

  return -Math.sqrt( dX ) * Math.sign( dY );

}

function clamp( val, min, max ) {

  return Math.min( Math.max( min, val ), max );

}

function dot( v0, v1 ) {

  return v0 * v1 + v0 * v1;

}
```

The goal is to calculate the distance from the point p to the triangle with the points p0, p1 and p2 with the function signedDistanceToTriangle.

As already described the function always returns NaN or wrong values.
Does anyone see the error and can help me?

Thx!

Comment: Haven't gone through the entire code, but the `dot` function looks very suspicious. You cannot calculate the dot product by only passing a single component of the vectors.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. Well possible! What do you think the dot function would look like correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` comes from the final `Math.sqrt(dX)` where `dX` is negative, calculating the correct dot product should mitigate this: `function dot(a,b) { return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y; }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried to adjust the dot function accordingly. Unfortunately it didn't work.